# Updating a record using passed variables

Tags: php, mysql

This Update Query seems to work inside MySQL WorkBench but when applying it to my php application doesn't want to work... Both the `$TotalSeats` & `$PerfID` parameters have been tested and they output the desired number.

Is this a minor syntax error or am I missing a trick here?

```
$deductSeats = "UPDATE perf SET Seats=(SELECT SUM(Seats -'$TotalSeats')) WHERE PerfID = '$PerfID'";
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$deductSeats))
            {
                echo 'Query Worked!<br>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Query Didnt Work<br>';
            }





$deductSeats = "deductSeats(`$TotalSeats`,`$PerfID`)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
$deductSeats = "UPDATE perf SET `Seats` = `Seats` - ".$TotalSeats." WHERE PerfID = ".$PerfID;

    if (mysqli_query($conn,$deductSeats)) {
        echo 'Query Worked!<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Query Didnt Work<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Still not working...I have created a stored procedure which is included in my post edit, but still having the issue

Comment: No error in particular, just the record not updating

Comment: So it's not a "dev" error as MySQL is not showing any error, but a logic error.

Comment: Agreed, this was the issue from the get go, while the page loaded with no errors, the no update occured, hence the echo statements to verify whether it did update

Comment: Marked it as solved, while the output statements didn't kick in as expected it seems your most recent solution did work, thanks for your time :)